# Why is cayoteTimeCounter equals to 0.5f though its not isGrounded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[cayoteTime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFix_Kg2Di0&t=126s)
but my code is working differently i can jump in the air several times

```
public class jump : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] float coyoteTime = 0.5f,coyoteTimeCounter = 0.0f;
    [SerializeField] float horizontalSpeed = 7.8f;
    [SerializeField] float horiMove;
    [SerializeField] float jumpVelocity = 7.5f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] bool isGrounded = false;

 
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();  
    }

  
    void Update()
    {
        horiMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        rb.transform.Translate(new Vector2(horiMove,0f));
        
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        }

        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && coyoteTimeCounter > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity += jumpVelocity * Vector2.up; //jumping
            coyoteTimeCounter = 0.0f; // equals to 0.0 but quickly changing to 0.5 (coyoteTime)
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
    
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }

    }
    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i was trying to jump in the air in 0.5 seconds just once but though my player is not grounded the

```
    if (isGrounded)
        {
        
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        }
```

still working so i can jump in the air several times because of that how can i fix it.
(im sorry for my English).

Comment: Can you confirm the values in the Inspector of your component match the ones in your script? The ones from the Inspector will always overrule.

Comment: Also you could try and remove the `OnCollisionStay2D` and instead rather directly set `isGrounded = false` when applying the jump input .. there is chance (actually a high one) that there is another `Update` call before the next physics update - they do not run in sync (see [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)) .. all collision messages are also called innthe same physics interval and not every frame

Comment: @derHugo Firstly Thanks for the answer "Also you could try and remove the OnCollisionStay2D and instead rather directly set isGrounded = false when applying the jump input" this is actually working but its arises another problem so i dont want to use it and instead of it i added isGroundedCounter to my code, its working correctly for now.